# Using .map() over a Map<K, V>() in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, dictionary, interface, prototype

I would like to extend the TypeScript `Map` type in my react TypeScript app to allow me to use `.map()`, in a similar way as you might with an `Array`.

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31084619/map-a-javascript-es6-map) that describes several methods, but the most natural to me for TypeScript is the answer by [Jeremy Lachkar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31084619/map-a-javascript-es6-map/70877028#70877028), although it isn't very popular. It means I don't have to introduce any awkward syntax in the client code and can just extend the `Map` object.

His code looks like this:

```
export {}

declare global {
    interface Map<K, V> {
        map<T>(predicate: (key: K, value: V) => T): Map<V, T>
    }
}

Map.prototype.map = function<K, V, T>(predicate: (value: V, key: K) => T): Map<K, T> {
    let map: Map<K, T> = new Map()

    this.forEach((value: V, key: K) => {
        map.set(key, predicate(value, key))
    })
    return map
}
```

I have augmented this to make it, for me, what seems more natural (I think the `Map<V, T>` in the interface might be a mistake in any case):

```
export {}

declare global {
  interface Map<K, V> {
    map<T>(predicate: (key: K, value: V) => T): Map<K, T>;
  }
}

Map.prototype.map = function<K, V, T>(predicate: (key: K, value: V) => T): Map<K, T> {
  let map: Map<K, T> = new Map();

  this.forEach((key: K, value: V) => {
    map.set(key, predicate(key, value));
  });

  return map;
}
```

This works great. I can now map over my `Map` and produce a new one. However, now none of the other methods on `Map`, such as `.set()`, are available to me, and my code throws errors. These are now `undefined`.

Any idea how to deal with this? I'm imagining in my little head that this might be a `tsconfig.json` issue of some sort, but I don't know.

Comment: [Don't extend builtin prototypes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14034180/why-is-extending-native-objects-a-bad-practice). Map already implements a `forEach` and you can very easily iterate the entries via `Map.entries()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Map2<K, V> extends Map<K, V> {
  map<T>(mapper: (value: V, key: K, map: this) => T): Map2<K, T> {
    let m = new Map2<K, T>;
    for (let [k, v] of this.entries()) {
      m.set(k, mapper(v, k, this))
    }
    return m;
  }
}

let m = new Map2([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
console.log(m)

let m2 = m.map(e => e + 10)
console.log(m2)
```

Making a subclass is generally a better idea then changing prototypes (tho that works well if you are the only one who changes prototypes)

```
declare global {
  interface Map<K, V> {
    map1<T>(mapper: (value: V, key: K, map: this) => T): Map2<K, T>
  }
}

Map.prototype.map1 = Map2.prototype.map

export {}
```

Comment: Hmm…am I to understand that I have to use a different name for my class? I mean, I could do that pretty easily, but I’d rather avoid it. Can’t I extend the class with an “extension” in the same way I might in, say, C#?

Comment: I am not at my computer right now, but wouldn’t that second block of code suffer from the same problem? That the existing methods would be made unavailable?

Comment: "extension" is modifying prototype, which you already did, and I did

Comment: Honestly I dunno why that didnt work for you, it works fine for me in tsplay.dev

Comment: Well, have you tried .set() on Map? Not Map2, but Map? I don’t really want to create a new class, just extend the existing one.

Comment: Well, you can, that's same, just has different angles ot clearness. set does work, see https://tsplay.dev/WylbZm

Comment: Thanks for your efforts, but the code doesn't work. Logging out `m1` at the end of your code snippet (after changing the module to CommonJS) yields an empty object. I'm just going to subclass and be done with it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, turns out it was my client code that was wrong, and that is why the `.set()` and so on were undefined. So the original post I referenced right at the top does it fact work.

I had imagined it was because redefining the interface had removed the other methods. Not so. Silly me.

As you were.